# An irreducible scheme whose extension of scalars is connected and not irreducible.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I have difficulty finding an example of an affine scheme such that satisfies

1 It is an affine scheme over the real number.

2 It is irreducible.

3 Its extension of scalers $\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ is connected and not irreducible.

I have spent some time on it. Thanks for any answers, hint or references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2)$ ?

Comment: Thanks! I can see this is non-irreducible over $\Bbb C$ and this is clear that it is irreducible over $\Bbb R$, but may I please ask how I see the connectedness of this scheme?

Comment: @PropositionX: An affine scheme $Spec(A)$ is not connected if and only if $A$ Is a direct product of two non-trivial rings ( rings $\ne 0$ ring).

Comment: Yes I was trying to prove it just now... But I cannot find a good way to prove that we have only 0 and 1 as idempotents... May I please ask for some possible way? Or the only way to do that is writting out a basis and conclude the element is idempotent only if it is 0 or 1?

Comment: @PropositionX: If $f(f-1) = 0$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x+i y)(x-iy)$ then $(x+i y) \mid f$ and $x-i y) \mid (1-f)$ so we have an equality $(x+i y) P(x,y) + (x -i y) Q(x,y) = 1$. Now put $y=0$ and get a contradiction.

Comment: Aha! Smart solution! Get it and thanks so much!